# Block reads different length of sequence gpu

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, gpu, nvidia, gpgpu

I have an array that has different length of sequences, each sequence ended by '>'.
seq = [ a,b,f,g,c,d,>,b,g,d,> ....]. I computed the length of each sequence and stored it in a different array called seq_length = [6,3,5,...]. Then, I use the exclusive scan in order to compute the offset and stored it in an array called offset=[0, 6, 9, ..].

What I want is let each block reads a sequence from the array seq[ ] by using the offset value. For example, block 0 reads the sequence that starts from seq[0] and stops when the length is =6, block 1 reads the sequence that starts from seq[6] and stops when the length is =3, and so one. 
How I can do that in CUDA?? How I can let each block reading from different ith array entry (array seq[]).

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

CUDA has [built-in variables](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#thread-hierarchy) like `threadIdx.x` and `blockIdx.x` that identify each thread within a block, and also which block that thread is in.  Every thread within a block will have the same `blockIdx.x` value, but each thread in a block will have a different/unique (per  block) `threadIdx.x` value.

Therefore, we can use `blockIdx.x` to select a specific sequence for each block.  This variable can be used to select the correct sequence length as well as the offset for each sequence/block.

We can assign one thread per block to each sequence item/character.  We can use `threadIdx.x` to identify, for each thread, which sequence member it should select.

Here is a fully worked example:

```
$ cat t405.cu
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void tk(char *seq, int *offsets, int *seq_lengths, int num_seq){

  if (blockIdx.x < num_seq)
   if (threadIdx.x < seq_lengths[blockIdx.x])
     printf("block: %d, thread: %d, seq: %c\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x, seq[offsets[blockIdx.x]+threadIdx.x]);
}

int main(){

  char seq[] = {'a','b','f','g','c','d','>','b','g','d','>','a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e', '>'};
  int seq_length[] = { 6, 3, 5 };
  int offsets[] = { 0, 7, 11 };
  int num_seq = 3;

  int seq_sz   = sizeof(seq);
  int seq_l_sz = sizeof(seq_length);
  int off_sz   = sizeof(offsets);

  char *d_seq;
  int *d_seq_length, *d_offsets;
  cudaMalloc(&d_seq, seq_sz);
  cudaMalloc(&d_seq_length, seq_l_sz);
  cudaMalloc(&d_offsets, off_sz);

  cudaMemcpy(d_seq, seq, seq_sz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_seq_length, seq_length, seq_l_sz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(d_offsets, offsets, off_sz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  tk<<<num_seq, 1024>>>(d_seq, d_offsets, d_seq_length, num_seq);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
  if (cudaSuccess != err) printf("cuda error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
  return 0;
}

$ nvcc -arch=sm_61 -o t405 t405.cu
$ ./t405
block: 1, thread: 0, seq: b
block: 1, thread: 1, seq: g
block: 1, thread: 2, seq: d
block: 2, thread: 0, seq: a
block: 2, thread: 1, seq: b
block: 2, thread: 2, seq: c
block: 2, thread: 3, seq: d
block: 2, thread: 4, seq: e
block: 0, thread: 0, seq: a
block: 0, thread: 1, seq: b
block: 0, thread: 2, seq: f
block: 0, thread: 3, seq: g
block: 0, thread: 4, seq: c
block: 0, thread: 5, seq: d
$
```

If you expect more than 1024 characters in a sequence, then you would want to modify the above, perhaps to have each thread handle multiple characters, perhaps in a loop.